# How to Make a Simple GUI with DropDown Menus with C++

Tags: c++, user-interface, mfc, cdialog, cwnd

I am really struggling how to make a window with three selections of options. I currently have a setup that uses a `CFileDialog` object and have successfully implemented two dropdown menus and multiple check items.

What I want is to implement a pop up window that has the two drop down menus and the check boxes. If a certain item is selected in one of the dropdown menus then the file dialog is opened.

Currently I am trying to make a `CWnd` object and try to write code for it there.

```
    CWnd myWindow;

    BOOL VALUE = myWindow.Create(_T("DesktopApp"), _T("test"), WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | WS_CAPTION,
        RECT{ 100,100,400,400 },
        myWindow.GetDesktopWindow(), 12);
    
    myWindow.ShowWindow(SW_SHOWNORMAL);
    

    if (VALUE == FALSE) {
        return 0;
    }
```

Every time I run this, it prematurely returns (`VALUE == FALSE`). Did I do something wrong? Is there a simpler way to create a window?

Comment: Maybe consider adding a `Windows` OS tag.

Comment: Have you registered a window class with the class name `"DesktopApp"`?

Answer (score 1):

The first argument to [`CWnd::Create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class#create) is the [window class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-classes) name. A class with the requested name must have been registered before it can be created.

It is common to register an [application local class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-window-classes#application-local-classes) for the application's main window. MFC provides a convenient wrapper function ([`AfxRegisterWndClass`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/application-information-and-management#afxregisterwndclass)) to register a window class.